# Python - Not Printing All Data

Tags: python

I created a code that constantly updates all the currency values around the world.
Currently with the code, it only displays the euro value, when it should display USD, Euro, Rupees, etc.  Could anyone please tell me why this is only displaying one value?

```
import time
import os
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def refresh():
    URL = "https://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=USD&amount=1"
    r = requests.get(URL) 

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser') 
    ratelist = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "ratesTable"})[0].findAll("tbody")

    for tableVal in ratelist:
        trList = tableVal.findAll('tr')
        for trVal in trList[:6]:
            print(trVal.text)
            time.sleep(5)
            os.system('cls')
            refresh()
refresh()
```

Have a good day,

```
        Bipolar Sheep
```

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't use recursion for this

Answer (score 0):

I would say your last refresh() statement should be outside of the for loops.

In your code, it refreshes after the first trVal has been printed, so it begins the refresh() statement once again. Please try this version :

```
import time
import os
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def refresh():
    URL = "https://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=USD&amount=1"
    r = requests.get(URL) 

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser') 
    ratelist = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "ratesTable"})[0].findAll("tbody")

    for tableVal in ratelist:
        trList = tableVal.findAll('tr')
        for trVal in trList[:6]:
            print(trVal.text)
            time.sleep(5)
    os.system('cls')
    refresh()

refresh()
```

EDIT : I also choose to drop the os.system('cls') from the loops.